# setInterval function of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript we use setInterval functions like this.

```
myInteval= setInterval("func",t);
```

What if the execution time of "func" itself is greater than interval time t ?

I think js is single threaded. How is this achieved ??

Comment: JS is not a single thread. You can fire multiple functions in the same time

Comment: There's no true threading in JavaScript.

Comment: No java script is single threaded... when we execute js code, it can only happen from one thread at a time.

Comment: javascript is single threaded..view this post on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718774/how-is-javascript-single-threaded

Comment: See [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval) for some decision of how timers work in JS.

Comment: @murali, please read [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Answer (score 7):

Then it will wait until `func` has finished executing, check the queue of functions to run on an interval, then run it again.

See [the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop) for more details.

Comment: Will the browser drop queued functions ? as it also has limits ? if they are dropped which function will be dropped first ?

Answer (score 1):

A few important things from this piece by John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

> ...timer delay is not guaranteed...

Which means, it is not essential that the `t` that you specify will be honoured as is. It indicates a minimum time and not a guaranteed time.

Further down:

> ...Intervals don’t care about what is currently executing, they will
>   queue indiscriminately, even if it means that the time between
>   callbacks will be sacrificed...

So, effectively the `func` will be queued to be executed without any `t` delay if the queue is accumulated due to execution.

And is summarized at the end:

> ...Intervals may execute back-to-back with no delay if they take long
>   enough to execute (longer than the specified delay).