# How to make an infinite loop with delay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make div which could change it color. Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    for (;;){
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector('style').style.backgroundColor = colors[rand(colors.length)];
        }, 2000);        
    }
}

var colors = [
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue',
    'yellow',
    'magenta',
    'pink'
];


var rand = function (max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};
```

```css
.style{
    background-color: pink;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="style"></div>
  </body>
```

But I can't find out why it doesn't work.
EDIT: the script also crashes the browser

Comment: Add your code here as well. There is a reason you can't include a jsfiddle link without any code here.

Comment: terrible formatting for someone with more than 100 rep..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

Comment: You have an infinite loop, that's why. The `setTimeout` callback can never be executed because the event loop can't proceed the next tick.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually it's not an infinite loop, but filling the task queue endlessly with new `setTimeout` tasks I'd say. The reason the browser crashes is simply a stack overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Single element

Assuming that your markup is this:

```
<body>
    <div id="my-id"></div>
</body>
```

To create a "color loop" you'll have to use [`setInterva()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) to set a function that will be executed infinite times (with a defined interval) to change the color. Here is the correct code:

```
var cur_color = -1,
    colors = [
        'red',
        'green',
        'blue',
        'yellow',
        'magenta',
        'pink'
    ];

var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('my-id').style.backgroundColor = colors[(++cur_color) % colors.length];
}, 2000);
```

This will change the color every 2 seconds. If you want to stop it, you can use the [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) function:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

### Multiple elements

Assuming your markup is:

```
<body>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
</body>
```

You can use the `getElementsByClassName()` method instead:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class');
    ++cur_color;
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) elements[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[cur_color % colors.length];
}, 2000);
```

### Working example

Here's a working example with multiple elements:

```js
var cur_color = -1,
    colors = [
        'red',
        'green',
        'blue',
        'yellow',
        'magenta',
        'pink'
    ];

var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class');
    ++cur_color;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) elements[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[cur_color % colors.length];
}, 2000);
```

```css
.my-class {
    background-color: pink;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) function.

Also, instead of `style`, you need `.style` selector (the class selector). If you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you may use `$(".style")` instead of `document.querySelector(...)`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('.style').style.backgroundColor = colors[rand(colors.length)];
    //$('.style').css("backgroundColor", colors[rand(colors.length)]);
  }, 2000);
}

var colors = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'magenta',
  'pink'
];


var rand = function(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};
```

```css
.style {
  background-color: pink;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="style"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is no need of jQuery at all.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli True, wasn't the question tagged with jQuery?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I see, but I was checking out jQuery questions... Maybe I came here from the newest questions on the side? Probably...

Answer (score 1):

See the code in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/k47rw5o4/embedded/result,js,html,css/), and my answer to [**this SO-question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380086/how-browser-execute-javascript-render-asynchronous)

You can't execute `setTimeout` in a loop. Create a function, and call it in a next `setTimeout`:

```
function changeColor() {
            document.querySelector('.style')
             .style.backgroundColor = colors[rand(colors.length)];
            setTimeout(changeColor,1000);
}
```

[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/086496gp/) your jsFiddle, rewritten