# Recursive async function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

I'm trying to write a recursive function using async/await in JavaScript.
This is my code:

```
async function recursion(value) {
  return new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      if(value == 1) {
        fulfil(1)
      } else {
        let rec_value = await recursion(value-1)
        fulfil(value + rec_value)
      }
    }, 1000)
    })
}

console.log(await recursion(3))
```

But I have syntax error:

```
let rec_value = await recursion(value-1)
                              ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd write your code as follows:

```js
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function recursion(value) {
  if (value === 0) return 0;

  await timeout(1000);
  return value + await recursion(value - 1);
}

(async () => console.log(await recursion(3)))();
```

Comment: This is a much nicer way to write the code but it doesn't answer the question like @James answer.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't declared your `setTimeout` handler as `async` therefore the compiler doesn't recognise the `await` keyword. From the looks of it you don't actually need it at the top level so you can update as:

```
function recursion(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            // use await keyword
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`let rec_value = await recursion(value-1)`

You can only await within an async function thus the JS engine is unable to parse the code.

Instead modify the usage to below since a async function always returns a Promise.

`recursion(value-1).then((value) => { console.log(value)})`

Refer to detailed documentation here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function