# Set timeout inside an async function with try and catch does not catch error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, ionic3, es6-promise

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I use [async and await](https://javascript.info/async-await) of ES6 features for syntactic sugar of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I know this is just a little bit basic question or because I am just new in using **async and await** feature.

Now the problem is I had a `setTimeout` inside my async function of `signI`n method to **authenticate** the user.

This is my code below:

```
async signIn() {
    try {
      this.loader = true // Present a loader
      this.backgroundLoader = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: 'Signing you in...' });
      this.backgroundLoader.present();
      // Response from server
      const response: any = await this.authService.loginDriver(this.loginForm.value)
      console.log(response)
      if (response.status == 200) { // If success response
        const token = await this.storage.set('token', response.data.token)
        console.log('token:', token)
        this.events.publish('driver:authenticated') // Broadcast an event that the driver has authenticated
        setTimeout(async () => {  // Dismiss the loader after successfull authentication
          try {
            const meDetails = await this.driverMe.getDriverMeInfo() // Get the profile information of the driver if
            console.log(meDetails)
          } catch (err) { console.log(err) } 
          this.backgroundLoader.dismiss();
          this.loader = false 
          this.navCtrl.setRoot("HomePage")
          this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
        }, 1500);
      }
    } catch(err) { // If something goes wrong or an error occured
      console.log(err)
      this.backgroundLoader.dismiss();
      this.loader = false 
      err.status == 401 || 422 // Something wrong in your authentication credentials
        ? this.alertMessage.alertMessage('Incorrect email or password', null) 
        : this.alertMessage.alertMessage('Something went wrong.', 'Please try again.') // Other errors not related to the data entry to be authenticated
    }
  }
```

The function does a basic **authentication** to send a post request to an **API server** and get the **response token** and put it on a **Storage** and use that token for every request that needs **authentication middleware** in the **backend**.

Actually there is no **error** in my code it works great. But if you look at the `try and catch` inside the `setTimeout` method. It looks uglier. The purpose of the `try and catch` is to catch an error for every **promises** but I am redeclaring it again inside the `setTimeout` function.

I'm not sure but I think this is happening because of the callback function on the `setTimeout` is a new `async and await` that's why it wont catch the error outside.

So my question really is there a way to handle this? To avoid redeclarations of `try and catch` inside a **setTimeout** method.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Is there anyway to handle this using one `try and catch`

Comment: You have to get rid of the raw `setTimeout` and wrap it with a promise, so that it integrates with `async`/`await`. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/14955

Comment: @Thilo so I would make a setTimeout function in a generic way and wrap it into a promises then pass the milliseconds as a argument right? and execute the next line of function after that.

Comment: You'd want to `await` the promise returned from your timeout. If you don't, it will not catch any exceptions.