# Fetch call every 2 seconds, but don't want requests to stack up

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

I am trying to make an API call and I want it to repeat every 2 seconds. However I am afraid that if the system doesn't get a request back in 2 seconds, that it will build up requests and keep trying to send them. How can I prevent this?

Here is the action I am trying to `fetch`:

```
const getMachineAction = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch( 'https://localhost:55620/api/machine/');
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("Machine successfully found.");
            const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
            console.log(myJson);               
        } else {
            console.log("not a 200");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // catches errors both in fetch and response.json
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

And then I call it with a `setInterval`.

```
function ping() {
    setInterval(
        getMachineAction(),
        2000
    );        
}
```

I have thought of doing some promise like structure in the setInterval to make sure that the fetch had worked and completed, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Is every 2 seconds an exact requirement?  If not, don't do it every 2 seconds.  Use `setTimeout` and schedule the next 2 seconds after the previous finishes instead.

Comment: There will be a set time, whether it is 2 seconds, or 30 seconds will depend on a variable, but it will stay consistent. (so if it is set to every 2 seconds, then it needs to happen every 2 seconds)

Comment: Maybe look into [throttling/debouncing](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) - I forget which is which. lodash has both methods.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the previous request at the 2 second mark? Should it cancel? What is your "bad case" requirement?

Comment: @zero298 the "bad case" (i.e. it takes longer than 2 seconds) is I want it to skip that request, and then send a single new one. So at 0 seconds the request sends. It takes 3 seconds to execute, then 2 seconds later (at 5) it should reexcute. So it just extends the time until it sends.

Comment: @Andy Neither of these will help here

Comment: @Bergi, I agree. do you have any recommendations? I am inclined to think charlietfl 's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @thalacker takrishna's approach is the way to go. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The **Promise.all()** Solution

This solution ensures that you don't miss-out on 2 sec delay requirement AND also don't fire a call when another network call is underway.

```js
function callme(){
//This promise will resolve when the network call succeeds
//Feel free to make a REST fetch using promises and assign it to networkPromise
var networkPromise = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');


//This promise will resolve when 2 seconds have passed
var timeOutPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // 2 Second delay
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'Timeout Done');
});

Promise.all(
[networkPromise, timeOutPromise]).then(function(values) {
  console.log("Atleast 2 secs + TTL (Network/server)");
  //Repeat
  callme();
});
}
callme();
```

Note: This takes care of the bad case definition as requested by the author of the question:

*"the "bad case" (i.e. it takes longer than 2 seconds) is I want it to skip that request, and then send a single new one. So at 0 seconds the request sends. It takes 3 seconds to execute, then 2 seconds later (at 5) it should reexcute. So it just extends the time until it sends."*

Comment: Seems like this would work really well. Would the `callme()` function or the `networkPromise` be my `getMachineAction`?

Comment: networkPromise  will be getMachineAction - callme is just a wrapper !! Good luck with your coding

Comment: I see that now. Ugh, dumb mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could add a `finally` to your `try/catch` with a `setTimeout` instead of using your `setInterval`.

Note that long polling like this creates  lot more server load than using websockets which themselves are a lot more real time

```
const getMachineAction = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch( 'https://localhost:55620/api/machine/');
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("Machine successfully found.");
            const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
            console.log(myJson);               
        } else {
            console.log("not a 200");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // catches errors both in fetch and response.json
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        // do it again in 2 seconds
        setTimeout(getMachineAction , 2000);
    }
};

getMachineAction()
```

Comment: Note that this makes it happen 2000 seconds after the request has finished, not 2000 seconds after the request was started.

Comment: @charlietfl do you have a websockets resource you would recommend checking out or reading about?

Comment: What language are you running in back end? Just do a search <language> websockets. If it is a node server check out socket.io

Comment: @charlietfl I am running a C#, .NET Core Web API. I can search for C# web sockets.

Primarily connecting to it via external devices to collect data

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Just store whether it's currently making a request, and store whether the timer has tripped without sending a new request.

```
let in_progress = false;
let missed_request = false;
const getMachineAction = async () => {
    if (in_progress) {
        missed_request = true;
        return;
    }
    in_progress = true;
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:55620/api/machine/');
        if (missed_request) {
            missed_request = false;
            setTimeout(getMachineAction, 0);
        }
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("Machine successfully found.");
            const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
            console.log(myJson);               
        } else {
            console.log("not a 200");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // catches errors both in fetch and response.json
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        in_progress = false;
    }
};
```

To start the interval, you need to omit the `()`:

```
setInterval(getMachineAction, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi @wizzwizz4, this would likely work if I was okay skipping requests, (i.e. execute at 2,4,8,10 and it had skipped 6), but I want it to work like it will execute asap and then go 2 seconds after that (i.e. execute at 2,4,7,9,10 where the 6 took an extra second so now its 2 seconds after).

Also, I think you need to set your `in_progress` variable to true in the first line after the `try`, right? Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @thalacker Yes, I do. (Or first line before, whatever works.) And this should do 2, 4, 6.3, 8, 10 if the one that starts on 4 takes 2.3 seconds, unlike charlietfi's solution. The `Promise.all` solution is neat, but seems to function almost identically to chatlietfi's solution (2, 4, 6.3, 8.3, 10.3). Which functionality were you looking for?