# async/await example not working. What am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to learn the concepts of async/await in javascript. I tried a simple code, to wait for a create post function to finish before calling the getPosts function, but the newly created post is not showing up. This is what I have tried out.

```js
const posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    body: "This is post one"
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    body: "This is post two"
  }
]

const newpost = {
  title: "Post Three",
  body: "This is post three"
}

function getPosts() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let output = '';
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      output += `<li>${post.title} : ${post.body}</li>`;
    });
    document.body.innerHTML = output;
  }, 1000);
}

function createPost(post) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(post);
  }, 2000);
}

async function init() {
  await createPost(newpost);
  getPosts();
}

init();
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `createPost()` doesn't return a promise

Comment: async/await only works with promises.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: All the answers below which says to create promise are mixing two concepts. Yes, await works with promises, but await is better used with async as mentioned in CMS's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56415196/1955268)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

createPost should return promise like below

```
function createPost(post) {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(post);
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
});  
}
```

Comment: Isn't using promises with await mixing two similar concepts? Promises are better used with `.then()` and `await` is better used with `async`

Comment: By default async returns promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `createPost` doesn't return a promise.

You can either return a promise manually:

```
function createPost(post) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(post);
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
  });  
}
```

But who want's to create promises by hand ? And since you want to practice with async functions, have `createPost` be an async function by itself.

I'm also extracting the `setTimeout` calls to a small `wait` async utility function:

```js
const posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    body: "This is post one"
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    body: "This is post two"
  }
]

const newpost = {
  title: "Post Three",
  body: "This is post three"
}

const sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

async function getPosts() {
  await sleep(1000);
  let output = '';
  posts.forEach((post, index) => {
    output += `<li>${post.title} : ${post.body}</li>`;
  });
  document.body.innerHTML = output;
}

async function createPost(post) {
    await sleep(2000);
    posts.push(post);
}

async function init() {
  await createPost(newpost);
  getPosts();
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

May I know why you're using `setTimeout()` function? removing the `setTimeout()` makes the code just work fine

```
 const posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    body: "This is post one"
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    body: "This is post two"
  }
]

const newpost = {
  title: "Post Three",
  body: "This is post three"
}

function getPosts() {
    let output = '';
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      output += `<li>${post.title} : ${post.body}</li>`;
    });
    document.body.innerHTML = output;
}

function createPost(post) {
    posts.push(post);
}

async function init() {
  await createPost(newpost);
  getPosts();
}

init();
```

Here is the working code pen:
[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvXMoK)

Answer (score 0):

createPost should return a promise so the function should be like that

```
function createPost(post) {
  return new Promise( resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => {
      posts.push(post);
      resolve()
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The await command expects the calling function to return a promise. Such a function usually execute an asynchronous command and resolves the promise when the command is successful.

```js
var posts = [];

function createPost(post) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(() => {
       posts.push(post);
       resolve();         //<- resolved the promise here
    }, 2000);


  })   

}


async function testAsync() {

    await createPost('a post');
    
    console.log(posts)
    
}

testAsync();
```

In this case, although Array.push() doesn't do any async operation, you call it via `setTimeout` to do it in an async fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Async/await only works with promises, so you need to wrap whatever code you have in `createPost()` in a promise, return it and then resolve it to indicate that it doesn't have to be awaited anymore and the code can continue executing. I made a tiny example from your code where you can see how it works:

```js
function getPosts(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log( "get posts" );
  }, 1000);
}

function createPost(post){
  return new Promise( res => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log( "post created" );
      res();
    }, 2000);
  } );
}

async function init(){
  await createPost();
  getPosts();
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

createPost is not any async function, await will listen only to promise and async function, to be able to await that kind of setTimeout, and to apply ur intent, u need promise with done method to tell Nodejs to end listening

```
function createPost(post) {
  return new Promise(done){
    setTimeout(() => {
      posts.push(post);
      done()
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```