# Is there a method to fix async functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Recently i have started to learn about async functions is JS
So i wrote a code that had to make a request, and with the data it received from the request, it should write in a CSV, the issue was that the write function hadn't waited for the request response, so it just wrote undefined.

In debugging purposes i wrote a new code to see how does async functions work, so i have the next situation

I have 3 functions log1(), log2(), main(),
I expect:

When I call main(), it should call log1(), wait until it finishes all the statements, and after that it should call log2()

So I wrote this code:

```js
function slowFunction(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('1')
  }, 2000);
}
function log1() {
  return new Promise(resolve =>{
    resolve(slowFunction())
  })
}
function log2() {
    console.log('2');
}

async function main() {
  var aux = await log1();
  log2();
}

main();
```

So I expected it to output

> 1
>
> 2

But it did output

> 2
>
> 1

I want to pay attention that I can't edit slowFunction, and you should perceive it like a function that needs an **unknown** amount of time to execute, so i need to wait for it that finishes, and after that the program should execute the log2();

Comment: Your slow function is not waiting for the timeout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout

Comment: With the timeout i just wanted to simulate a request

Comment: That request must be the promise since it is async.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `slowFunction`. It appears you want `slowFunction` to resolve after the timeout, but it returns immediately as currently written. You need to rewrite `slowFunction` to return a `Promise`, or maybe just rewrite `log1`:

```
function log1() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('1');
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually I wrote the timeout just for simulating a request, so I can't put the resolve in the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all async functions are wrapped with promise.

```js
function slowFunction(){
  return new Promise(resolve =>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("1")
    }, 2000);
  })
}

async function log1() {
  let ret = await slowFunction()
  console.log(ret)
}

function log2() {
  console.log('2');
}

async function main() {
  var aux = await log1();
  log2();
}

main();
```

Comment: I don't need a timeout for the resolve
With the timeout i simulated a request

So theoretically i can't change function 1 or 2