# Async/Await is not working as expected : ReactJS+ Async Await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, setstate

I am having problem in executing API calls using aysnc and await. I am using a data grid which has data , column and set of dropdown options for each column to implement column filtering(data and the dropdown options I am fetching from server).

The column config array is dependent on these options where each column is tagged with options corresponding to it. I have extracted this column filter as a separate component where I pass this options .

Fetch API calls to this server work in such a way that every time I query I get an ID, and then this ID is being passed to the next function to get the actual data.

So I query the table data first, then get the dropdown values and then set the column objects so that table gets rendered properly.

But the problem here is , with the way I have written the code it should work correcly. But when I just load the page it gives me error inside getColumnFilterValues saying "cannot read param of undefined" . With async/await the dropdown values should be available prior to setting the column data. But in my case it throws the above error.

Can someone tell what is going wrong here?

```
import * as React from "react";
const FETCH_ID_URL = "/fetch/id";
const FETCH_DATA_URL = "/fetch/data";


export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [], // hold table data
      columns: [], // hold column config
      dropDownValues: [], // hold column filter dropdown values
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchTableData(); // First fetching the table data
    await this.fetchDropDownValues(); // fetching the dropdown values for each column  
    this.setColumnData();  // then setting column object which is dependent on dropdown values
  }

  fetchDropDownValues = async () => {
    await this.fetchID(FETCH_ID_URL, payload, "dropDownValues");
  };

  fetchTableData = async () => {
    await this.fetchID(FETCH_ID_URL ,payload, "data");
  };

  fetchID = async (url, body, stateObject) => {
    try {
          const config = {
                          method: 'POST',
                          body: JSON.stringify(data)
                         }

         let response = await  fetch( url: FETCH_ID_URL, config);
         setTimeout(() => this.fetchData(response, stateObject), 2000); // Waiting for the ID to receive and then call fetchData
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  fetchData = async(obj: any, stateObject: string) => {
    try {
          const config = {
                          method: 'POST',
                          body: JSON.stringify(obj.id)
                         }
         let response = await  fetch( url: FETCH_DATA_URL, config);
         if (stateObject === "dropDownValues") {
           this.setState({ [stateObject]: response.dropdownData});
         } 
         else 
         {
            this.setState({[stateObject]: response.tableData});
         }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  getValuesFromKey = (param: string) => {
    let data: any = this.state.dropDownValues[param]; //Throwing error here , giving cant read param of undefined
    let result = data.map((value: any) => {
      let keys = Object.keys(value);
      return {
        field: keys[0],
        checked: false,
      };
    });
    return result;
  };


  setColumnData = () => {
     let columns = [
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
              <Child
                name="firstName"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey("firstName")}
              />
            <span>First Name</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
              <Child
                name="status"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey("status")}
              />
            <span>Status</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "status",
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  render() {
    let { data, columns } = this.state;
    return (
       <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the issue, but creating a `Promise` and actually returning it might help.

Comment: the problem is with setTimeout.


[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout) look at this discussio, you will get more insight from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```js
setTimeout(() => this.fetchData(response, stateObject), 2000); // Waiting for the ID to receive and then call fetchData
```

`this.setColumnData();` should be called after the `setTimeout` above has finished executing. In order to do so, you need to wrap the `setTimeout` in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await this.fetchData(response, stateObject);
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
});
```