# How can I make the setTimeout function synchronous?

Tags: javascript

My code gives output (with a delay between lines):

```
one
three
((2 seconds delay))
two
```

How can I make the code synchronous so that it shows output:

```
one
((2 seconds delay))
two
three
```

The code:

```js
console.log('one'); 
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('two');
}, 2000);
console.log('three');
```

Comment: You cannot make `setTimeout()` synchronous.

Comment: Just don't use `setTimeout`!

Comment: Are you asking us how to freeze your browser(window) for 2 seconds?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/3634032

Comment: You can use promises with setTimeout to achieve this! The trick is to resolve the promise when the setTimeout finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function x() {
  var promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("2"), 3000));
  return promise;
}
async function y() {
  console.log("1");
  var y = await x();
  console.log(y);
  console.log("3");
}
y();
```