# Rewrite promises to async/await when setTimeout() is used

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have two functions that are written with promises:

```
const resolvedDelay = (value, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value),ms));
const rejectedDelay = (value, ms) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(value),ms));
```

I try to rewrite them via async/await. This is my wrong attempt:

```
const resolvedDelay = async (value, ms) => setTimeout(() => value,ms); // I haven't reference to `resolve` here... :(
const rejectedDelay = async (value, ms) => setTimeout(() => {throw new Error(value)},ms);
```

How to do it right?

Comment: Using `async` makes only sense if you want to `await` promises inside the function. Since `setTimeout` has nothing to do with promises, you cannot make use of `async` either. The first way is the only correct way.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33289726/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a promise first in order to do anything useful with `await`.  And, since `setTimeout()` doesn't create a promise and doesn't resolve or reject a promise, you HAVE to create a promise and tie it to the `setTimeout()` callback just like you did in your first code block.

Your second code block just calls `setTimeout()` and immediately returns.  Wrapping it in an `async` makes it return a promise, but that promise is just immediately resolved when the function returns after calling `setTimeout()`.  So, you have to be resolving or rejecting a promise when the `setTimeout()` callback fires and there is no way to do that with just an `async` function wrapper around it.

Therefore, there's no real use for `async/await` in creating your two functions.  Your first group of functions where you manually create a promise is the way to go here.

Of course, the caller can use `await` with your first set of functions just fine without change.

Answer (score 1):

Usually something like this is done to convert the setTimeout into a reusable promise, which is then awaitable.

```
const delay = time => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));

const resolvedDelay = async (value, ms) => {await delay(ms); return value;}; 
const rejectedDelay = async (value, ms) => {await delay(ms); throw Error(value);};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, I don't know of a way of doing it that would make it remain as an arrow function though.

```
function resolvedDelay(value, ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value);
        }, ms);
    });
}

function rejectedDelay(value, ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value);
        }, ms);
    });
}

async function callFunctions() {
    const resolved = await resolvedDelay();
    const rejected = await rejectedDelay();

    // Do whatever you want with them now
}
```