# How do I use async/await in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following code:

```
function one() {

    setTimeout(() => {

        console.log('one');
    }, 2000);
}

function two() {
    console.log('two');
}

function three() {
    console.log('three');
}

function wrapper() {
    one();
    two();
    three();
}

wrapper();
```

This of course console logs them in the following order:
two
three
one

Using async / await I'd like to console log them in the following order:
one
two
three

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Comment: it's already implemented in most browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. if you want old IE support you need babel/webpack

Comment: Just wondering why my question was down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make use of [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). 
*Please have a look at the documentation.*

The code below returns a **Promise call**. The Promise itself sets a timeout of *two seconds* and after this time it logs "one" to the console.

You can wait for the promise to finish using the `await`-keyword right before the **function call**.

Note that the functions have to be async.

```
 return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('one');
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
  })
```

---

Heres a updated version of your code - I hope this helps:

```js
async function one() {
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('one');
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
  })
}

async function two() {
  console.log('two');
}

async function three() {
  console.log('three');
}

async function wrapper() {
  await one();
  await two();
  await three();
}

wrapper();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function one(){ 
  await new Promise(resolve => 
  setTimeout(async () => {
     await resolve(console.log('one'));
    }, 2000));
 
}

function two() {
    console.log('two');
}

function three() {
    console.log('three');
}
async function wrapper(){ await one(); two(); three();}

wrapper();
```

Comment: Why do we need setTimeout. This will just delay the output and "one" will never be populated first. Let's focus on the required output.

Comment: Ok, so I've edited by applying the setTimeout. Does this satisfy the query.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As far as I can tell this is exactly what OP is after. I've retracted my downvote. One last remark: it is always recommended to add an explanation of what changes you made so OP and future visitors can learn from it/know how to apply it themselves.