# How to run JavaScript functions in order (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a small react App that presents documents from a SharePoint site.

To make the App work correctly I am having to add setTimeouts, but I know there must be a better way using callbacks or promises or something >.<

My knowledge is lacking, so could somebody please point me in the right direction?

```
  // Handles what runs when the drop down is changed
  public handleDropdownChange(e) {

    // Updates dropdown select
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value, isLoading: true });

    // Checks security permissions - MAKES A GET REQUEST
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getSecurityGroupUsers();
    }, 1000); 

   // Ghecks if user can access docs
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.checkForDocAccess();
    }, 2000); 

    // Gets documents - MAKES A GET REQUEST
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getDocuments();
    }, 4000); 

    // Delete Mark as Reviewed property THEN displays docs
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hideMarkAsReviewed();
    }, 8000);

  }
```

One of the functions:

```
  // Grabs the documents
  public getDocuments() {

    axios
      .get("https://bpk.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='owstaxIdDocumentx0020Owner:" + this.state.selectedOption + "'&trimduplicates=true&rowsperpage=100&rowlimit=1000&selectproperties='LastReviewDateOWSDATE,ScheduledReviewDateOWSDATE,Path'",
        { params:{},
          headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        })
      .then(response =>
          response.data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.map(document => ({
            Type: this.checkFile(document),
            Name: document.Cells.results[6].Value.split("/").pop(),
            'Scheduled Review Date': document.Cells.results[8].Value.slice(0,-11),
            Path: document.Cells.results[6].Value.replace('https://bpkintelogydev.sharepoint.com', ''),
            Site: document.Cells.results[6].Value.split('/').slice(4).slice(0,1),
            'Last Review Date': document.Cells.results[7].Value.slice(0,-11),
            View: <a href="#" onClick={()=>window.open(document.Cells.results[6].Value + '?web=1&action=edit')}>View</a>,
            'Mark as Reviewed': <a href='#'>Mark</a>
        }))
      )
      .then(documents => {
        this.setState({documents, isLoading: true});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        //console.log(error);
      });

  }
```

Comment: You may benefit from using `async` and `await`. More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Have you looked into async/await?

Comment: [You could do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/9523162) to make a sleep function then just sleep before each call.

Comment: @meyi - That would be just as bad as `setTimeout`.

Comment: Why don't you chain them with `.then()`?

Comment: the setState has a callback function.

Comment: wow my answers downvoted for giving you the answer to how to make a callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, callbacks or promises are what you do here. Promises would be the more modern way (not least so you can use `async`/`await` with them). `setState` provides a callback for when the state is set if you want that (it's an optional second argument to `setState`). Then your various functions (`getSecurityGroupUsers`, etc.) would return promises that they fulfill or reject.

In your `getDocuments`, for instance, you want to:

1. `return` the result of calling `then`, and
2. **Don't** have an error handler, leave that to `handleDropdownChange`

...and similar in the others. For any that don't already have a promise to chain on (`getDocuments` has the one from `axios`) because they use a callback-style API you can create a promise and fulfill/reject it yourself (see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) for details there).

Doing that, `handleDropdownChange` might look something like:

```
// Handles what runs when the drop down is changed
public handleDropdownChange(e) {
    // Updates dropdown select
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value, isLoading: true });

    this.getSecurityGroupUsers()
    .then(() => this.checkForDocAccess())
    .then(() => this.getDocuments())
    .then(() => this.hideMarkAsReviewed())
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    });
}
```

or if you didn't want to start those until the state had been changed initially:

```
// Handles what runs when the drop down is changed
public handleDropdownChange(e) {
    // Updates dropdown select
    this.setState(
        { selectedOption: e.target.value, isLoading: true },
        () => {
            this.getSecurityGroupUsers()
            .then(() => this.checkForDocAccess())
            .then(() => this.getDocuments())
            .then(() => this.hideMarkAsReviewed())
            .catch(error => {
                // ...handle/report error...
            });
        }
    );
}
```

In this *particular* case, `async`/`await` doesn't help much, but perhaps some. I assume `handleDropdownChange` shouldn't be `async` since it's an event handler and so nothing would handle the promise it would return, so:

```
// Handles what runs when the drop down is changed
public handleDropdownChange(e) {
    // Updates dropdown select
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value, isLoading: true });

    (async () => {
        try {
            await this.getSecurityGroupUsers();
            await this.checkForDocAccess();
            await this.getDocuments();
            await this.hideMarkAsReviewed();
        } catch (error) {
            // ...handle/report error...
        }
    })();
}
```

Notice how the entire body of the `async` function is in a `try`/`catch`, because nothing hooks its promise, so it's important we handle errors directly. (Ensure that "handle/report error" doesn't throw an error. :-) )

Comment: This helps alot thankyou! I am going to watch a few videos on JS async,promises,callbacks,etc and then come back to this post and hopefully I can implement this with understanding and make my code better :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use Async await for waiting promise to resolve

```
public handleDropdownChange = async e => {

   this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value, isLoading: true });

   await this.getSecurityGroupUsers();

   await this.checkForDocAccess();

   await this.getDocuments();

   await this.hideMarkAsReviewed();
}
```

Comment: 1. Making `handleDropdownChange` itself an `async` function is likely to be incorrect, since it looks like an event handler and so nothing is going to do anything with the promise it returns. 2. `await` won't do anything if the functions in question don't return promises (which the OP's `getDocuments` doesn't). 3. Since `handleDropdownChange` appears to be an event handler function, it should handle errors, since its caller won't.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function call back!

```
function functionOne(x) { return x; };

function functionTwo(var1) {
    // some code
}

functionTwo(functionOne);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use async await and a simple sleep function to wait between them if it is required

```js
const sleep = time => new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(res, time);
});

async handleDropdownChange(e) {

    // Updates dropdown select
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value, isLoading: true });

    // Checks security permissions - MAKES A GET REQUEST
    await sleep(1000);
    await this.getSecurityGroupUsers();
    
    await sleep(1000);

   // Ghecks if user can access docs
   await this.checkForDocAccess(); 

   await sleep(1000);
    // Gets documents - MAKES A GET REQUEST
    await this.getDocuments();
    
    await sleep(1000);
    // Delete Mark as Reviewed property THEN displays docs
    await this.hideMarkAsReviewed();
  }
  
  // But you methods should return a promise like this
  
  getDocuments = () => {
     return fetch('some url').then(res => res.json());
  }
  
  // Or something like
  getSecurityGroupUsers = async () => {
    const data = await axios('some url');
    return data.message;
  }
```

Comment: Why would you need sleep when each function call is await'ed?

Comment: @marekful Read my comment. `sleep function to wait between them if it is required`