# Wait for a function until it has finished its setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

i want to know if there is a way i can wait for a function that has a structure similar to this :

```js
function foo(){
    //do stuff
    setTimeout(()=>{
     
       //do more stuff

    },timeout)

    // do even more stuff

}
```

i tried using `utils.promisify` but it tends not to wait for the `settimeout` to finish before proceeding to the "then" callback function.

here is an example :

```js
const promise=promisify(foo);
promise().then(alert("ok"));
```

the alert seems to trigger way before the settimeout is finished executing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Comment: `alert` is called first because you call it first. You have to pass a function reference to `.then`: `.then(() => alert('ok'))`. `promisify` will still not work because `foo` isn't a function that can be promisified. Look at the linked question to learn how to properly combine promises and `setTimeout`.

Comment: No, there is no way to wait for that function. You will need to change its structure so that it accepts a callback or returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using the Promise constructor and resolve or reject

```
let  a = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) { setTimeout(
    function() {
      resolve("whatever");
    }, timeout});

a.then(alert("ok"));
```

Comment: `alert` will still be called first. You have to pass a function to `.then`.