# Make the function call synchronous

Tags: javascript

```
function first(){
    console.log("1")
}

function second(){
     new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("2")
            resolve();
        } ,0);

     })  
}

function third(){
    console.log("3")
}

 async function run(){
   
    first();
    await second();
    third();

}

run();
```

Need to make the function call sync to get final output as 1,2,3 i tried creating the promise and use  async await but that didnt help any other way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Comment: What does this resolve(...) do? And what is your actual task? What are you expected to do here? Change the run method so it would print them in order? Or what?

Comment: Where does this `resolve`  come from, and what does it do?

Comment: @Bergi have updated the question sorry it was my mistake

Comment: @SwarupChavan Thanks, that's making a lot more sense now. The only problem is that you forgot to `return` the created promise from the `second` function, so you're `await`ing  `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pack the setTimeout into a promise and resolve in setTimeout,

Use async await for that promise in order for that to run consecutively

```js
function first() {
  console.log("1")
}

function second() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("2");
      res()
    }, 0)
  })

}

function third() {
  console.log("3")
}

async function run() {

  first();
  await second()
  third();
}

run();
```