# Why setTimeout function is non blocking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, settimeout, event-loop

If setTimeout is synchronous why its non blocking? On which thread does it execute if not main thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Comment: The reason it's like this is that setTimeout predates promises.

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous - but it does not have a `Promise`-API. The basic functionality of asynchronous functions is not `Promises`, but `Callbacks` (meaning giving a function that gets called asynchronously`. That's the function you pass into `setTimeout()`  as a first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout is synchronous in nature. Its callback get registered by event loop in timer phase which will be executed an asynchronous manner.

Answer (score 1):

> Why setTimeout function does not return a promise?

Primarily because it predates Promises being added to the JS language.

> Is setTimeout synchronous or asynchronous?

It runs synchronously and queues a function to run *later*.

> why does setTimeout does not return a promise but a number?

It returns a number for use with `clearTimeout`.

> Can we use await on setTimeout?

You can only usefully `await` a promise.

---

You can [wrap a call to `setTimeout` in a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) and `resolve` it from the callback function you pass to `setTimeout`.

```
await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    // do whatever you like after 1s
    // then:
    resolve();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: if it is synchronous why it is not blocking?

Comment: @user5573523 — It queues a function to run later. It doesn't do any processing asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout function is asynchronous that is why it is non blocking. It is executed on main thread.
Timeout function are executed as follows:

> The callbacks of timers in JavaScript(setTimeout, setInterval) are
> kept in the heap memory until they are expired. If there are any
> expired timers in the heap, the event loop takes the callbacks
> associated with them and starts executing them in the ascending order
> of their delay until the timers queue is empty.