# Node.js Puppeteer How To Await For page.evaluate() Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer, es6-promise

I need to wait for scrolling action to finish, then resolve.

When I put resolve() inside page.evaluate() block it throws:
(node:22646) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: resolve is not defined

If I keep it like this It resolves immediately.

```
let scrollingPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    page.evaluate(() => {
        const scrollingWindow = document.querySelector('.section-layout.section-scrollbox.scrollable-y.scrollable-show');            
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                scrollingWindow.scrollBy(0, 3000);
            }, 2000 * i);
        }
    });
    resolve();
});
```

SOLVED
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/844

Comment: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args — The first paragraph after the bulleted list will probably be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the for loop, don't know what it is there for

```
function scroll(){
    return page.evaluate(() => {
        const scrollingWindow = document.querySelector('.section-layout.section-scrollbox.scrollable-y.scrollable-show');
        return new Promise(resolve=>{
            setTimeout(function () {
                scrollingWindow.scrollBy(0, 3000);
                resolve();
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
}
```