# slow down the cycle( for of)?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cycle

how can you slow down the cycle for of? Displays all values ​​at once

```
for (var [key, value] of Array.from(groups).reverse()) { 
    
    setTimeout(function(){     // this does not work
    console.log('test');
    }, 3000);
    
    }
```

Comment: [Related problem with potentially useful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple asynchronous functions

```
const delay = async time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

;(
 async () => {
for (var [key, value] of Array.from(groups).reverse()) { 
    
     await delay(3000)
     console.log('test')
    }
}
)()
```