# async/await Discord.js Node.js Javascript JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js

Hey I hope someone can help me with my problem.

The following code should Output:

Hello
World!
Goodbye!

But it doesn`t wait for the second Line to be execute.

So the Output is
Hello
Goodbye!
World!

```html
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "02";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "help" || command === "h" || command === "hilfe"){

    console.log("Hello");
    await setTimeout(() => { console.log("World!"); }, 2000);
    console.log("Goodbye!");
    }

});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: `await` keyword only works on promise. `setTimeout` does not return a promise, thus it won’t work.

Comment: alternatively, you can put all the `console.log` code inside your `setTimeout`. and take a look in this question [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to promisify the `setTimeout` logic so that `await` can work with it. Consider this `sleep` function implementation.

```js
function sleep(timeInMs) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeInMs);
  });
}

// usage
async message => {
  // …
  console.log("Hello");
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("World!");
  console.log("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot