# Get await value inside loop and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, async-await, userscripts

I store a value locally like this:

```
await GM.setValue("current_page_url", current_page_url);
```

Then I loop through an object via `.each()` and after a timeout, attempt to *get* the value:

```
$j_object.each( function(){
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        var getting_page = await GM.getValue('current_page_url');
        alert(getting_page);
    }, 4000)

});
```

But it returns undefined. I believe this is because of how I'm using `await` inside the loop and `setTimeout()`, but not sure.

What's the correct approach?

Comment: `await` can only be used inside `async` functions - surely your console has an error regarding this

Answer (score 1):

There are a few considerations:

1. As mentioned by Jaromanda X, `await` goes with `async`
2. 'current_page_url' seems to be fixed so why would the script need to get it and run an asynchronous function on every loop reiteration?
3. What is the aim of `setTimeout` in a loop? It will run rapidly after the initial time-out i.e.

   - Loop 1: wait and run after 4 sec
   - Loop 2: faction of a millisecond later, wait and run after 4 sec
   - Loop 3: faction of a millisecond later, wait and run after 4 sec
   - etc

In practice, after 4 seconds, loop 1, 2, 3, etc will run one after the other.

Here is an example ...

```js
(async() => {

// wait to be set the value
await GM.setValue("current_page_url", current_page_url);

/* some code */

// wait to be get the value
const getting_page = await GM.getValue('current_page_url');

$j_object.forEach(function(){
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(getting_page);
    }, 4000)
});

})();
```

If you really need to run the asynchronous `GM.getValue()` in a loop. you can also use `then()` e.g.

```js
(async() => {

// wait to be set the value
await GM.setValue("current_page_url", current_page_url);

$j_object.forEach(function(){
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      GM.getValue('current_page_url').then(getting_page => console.log(getting_page));
    }, 4000)
});

})();
```

If you want to delay each reiteration by 4 seconds (e.g. so 5 reiteration takes 20 seconds), then you can check the answer in [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/3529456).