# Interview question, setTimeout should be called first before console.log

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I was asked this question in an interview yesterday, on how to change the code so that it gives the expected output. I got a hint that await can be used before callMe(delay) function.

```js
function callMe(delay) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Called');
    }, delay);
}

const delays = [500, 1000, 1500];
for (let delay of delays) {
    callMe(delay);
}
console.log('Completed');

//## Expected Output -
// Called
// Called
// Called
// Completed
```

This question has been bothering me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Comment: not to offend you but attending a JS interview without knowing this is like aaking to drive a car without knowing what is accelarator and break! this can help you get started - https://nodejs.dev/learn  after this if you like to do server programming then please considering researching express, mongodb, postgresql etc....also checkout lodash.com and bluebirdjs.com

Comment: @Nidhin David not really. I was stuck for a decade below ECMA6 as well since I had to maintain old intranet solutions for banks. I missed out on alot of the new *goodies* as well. Also your recommendations are questionable.. each employer has its own needs.

Comment: @JavaScript can you point to me a referene wherein settimeout executes synchronously in old JS, just curious to update my knowledge? Also you are free to question my recommendation and share yours as well!

Comment: @Nidhin David Where is that question coming from? I did not imply anything of that sort. However, I am sure you can think of a way to wait for a for loop which has a definite length and use a callback. And no, I do not share subjective recommendations, as you can read in my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```js
function callMe(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Called");
      // Resolve Promise, when Timeout is over
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}

// Async Main Function
(async () => {
  const delays = [500, 1000, 1500];
  for (let delay of delays) {
    // Await the Timeout with the Promise
    await callMe(delay);
  }
  console.log("Completed");
})();
```

The `callMe` function now returns a promise, so that it can get awaited

The main function is now async, as the `await` can only be used in async functions.
The `await` ensures that the timeout is done and only then it continues.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank you, please can you explain it in brief

Comment: Yes, so I've made callMe an Promise, which gets resolved, when the timeout is over. The main Part is now async, as I have to await the Promises to get resolved.
I am basically awaiting the timeouts and after they get resolved I continue with the next Promise

Comment: `callMe()` does not need to be `async` since it returns a promise.