# SetTimeout for an async await function fo retrieve new data

Tags: javascript, async-await

I would this function to run every 5 seconds and get new data. The `getGas()` function is an `async-await` function in and of itself and works fine if I just call `let gas = await getGas();`. The issue is that I need it to run every 5 seconds and get a new gas price. I'm having trouble understanding how to call this function and have it run every 5 seconds.

```
async function main() {
  // get the current gwei prices & new price every 5 seconds

  let gas = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      await getGas();
    }, 5000);
  };

  console.log(gas);

  // other code down here
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.. I would just make the `setTimeout` a `Promise` in itself and then have gas as an `async function` to call..

```js
async function main() {
  // get the current gwei prices & new price every 5 seconds

  let gas = async () => {
    return new Promise(r=>{
      setTimeout(async()=>r(await getGas()),5e3);
    })
  }

  console.log(await gas()); //whatever getGas should be

  // other code down here

  //whenever you want gas, you can just "await gas()"
}
```

However.. if you just didn't word your question correctly and you want the variable `gas` to be updated every 5 seconds in that block of code *within recalling main*

an `async function` to call..

```js
async function main() {
  // get the current gwei prices & new price every 5 seconds

  let gas = null; //starting value
  setInterval(async()=>gas=await getGas(),5e3); //every 5 seconds, gas is updated

  console.log(gas); //null
  setTimeout(()=>console.log(gas),6e3); //whatever getGas should be
  // other code down here

  //whenever you want gas, you can just "gas"
}
```

**EDIT**: you told me it doesn't work so I give a live example and am now asking *how*

```js
async function getGas(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*5)
}

async function main1() {
  // get the current gwei prices & new price every 5 seconds

  let gas = async () => {
    return new Promise(r=>{
      setTimeout(async()=>r(await getGas()), 5e3);
    })
  }

  setInterval(async()=>
    console.log(await gas(),"~ main1") //whatever getGas should be
  ,1e3);
  // other code down here

  //whenever you want gas, you can just "await gas()"
}

async function main2() {
  // get the current gwei prices & new price every 5 seconds

  let gas = null; //starting value
  setInterval(async()=>gas=await getGas(),5e3); //every 5 seconds, gas is updated

  console.log(gas); //null
  setInterval(()=>
    console.log(gas,"~ main2") //whatever getGas should be
  ,1e3);
  // other code down here

  //whenever you want gas, you can just "gas"
}
main1(); main2();
```

Comment: Yup, every 5 seconds. So when running the second code it runs perfectly. But doesn't seem to update ```gas``` with new prices. Just with the prices from the first time it ran.

Comment: @itzmurd4 both attempts don't work?

Comment: @itzmurd4 here is a live example proving that it works.. didn't you see the comments showing how to get the ever updating value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `setTimeout` for that then the callback needs to invoke the function that calls `setTimeout` again, e.g.

```
(async function main() {
  const gas = await getGas();
  // do stuff with gas

  setTimeout(main, 5000); // call main again after 5 seconds
}());
```

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot recall main. The gas variable has needs to update whatever is inside of main and main runs continuously until the user stops.

Comment: Why can't you recall `main`? @itzmurd4.

Comment: because there's another function within main that run continuously sending transactions to the blockchain as each new block is mined. If i run main again, it would send multiple transactions every 5 seconds onto the same block. So its essentially listening for a new block and then sending a new tx.

Comment: @itzmurd4:  You can put that logic into another function if necessary. You are not providing a lot of information about your problem (e.g. how `gas` is going to be used). Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Mine is a valid answer to the problem *"I would this function to run every 5 seconds and get new data."* If your problem is more complex, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setTimeout` doesn't need to be wrapped in its own `async` function. Just call `main`, log the data, and then call `main` again.

```js
function mockApi(page) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(page), 1000);
  });
}

async function main(page = 1) {
  const data = await mockApi(page);
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
  setTimeout(main, 1000, ++page);
}

main();
```