# Why does the table changes data some time after the promise has already been fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

When i run the code:

```
async function test(){
    let table=[];
    setTimeout(() => {
      table[0]='resolved';    }, 300);
    return table;
}

let result;

test().then(res=>{
  result=res;
  console.log("first  -" + result);
});

setTimeout(() => {
     console.log("second -" + result)
    }, 4000);
```

i expect to get:

```
first  - []
second - []
```

but the result is:

```
first  - []
second - ['resolved']
```

why does this happen? Since the function test has already been fulfilled when it gets to the first console.log, why does the result changes?

Comment: You are not awaiting for the timeout to conclude in the test() function. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939030/6262162). Basically, you need to wrap your timeout in a Promise.

Comment: @SakisTsalk yes but exactly because i am not wrapping the timeout in a Promise and not awaiting for it to resolve, shouldn't the result always be an empty [ ]? Because the function test returns the table empty since the timeout hasn't been executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript [passes and returns by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7744611/1426891), but the array `[]` is an object, and returning the result or assigning it to a variable doesn't make a copy of that object. All three names—`table`, `res`, and `result`—all refer to that same array object, so when the code in `setTimeout` changes the array, then you see it in `result` later on.

```js
// primitives like numbers and strings pass by value
let string1 = "abc";
let string2 = string1;
string2 = "def";
console.log(string1 + " / " + string2); // abc / def

let number1 = 123;
let number2 = number1;
number2 = 456;
console.log(number1 + " / " + number2); // 123 / 456

// if you replace the reference to the array, then they coexist
let array1 = [234];
let array2 = array1;
array2 = [567];
console.log(array1 + " / " + array2); // 234 / 567

// but if you modify it in place, then there's only one object
// so the modification shows in both places
let array3 = [345];
let array4 = array3;
array4.push(678);
console.log(array3 + " / " + array4); // 345,678 / 345,678
```

Your function `test` returns an array object, and that object is the object passed to `then` and saved in `result`. However, the browser (or other environment) still runs the `setTimeout` code, changing the contents of the array even after the reference to the array was saved to `res` and `result`.

For this reason, you have to be very careful when working with an array you've received as a variable: If you need to ensure it doesn't change unexpectedly, you might need to make your own copy of the array. Otherwise, the  caller might change the array out from under you, exactly the way that your `setTimeout` does in `test`.