# Asynchronous call stack execution gap

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am reading "Eloquent JavaScript" and at the end of Asynchronous chapter there is a section about execution gap in asynchronous operations and it shows an example. The example code below from the book is not runable as it uses some made up scenario.

```
function anyStorage(nest, source, name) {
   if (source == nest.name) return storage(nest, name); else return routeRequest(nest, source, "storage", name);
}

async function chicks(nest, year) {
   let list = "";
   await Promise.all(network(nest).map(async name => {
     list += `${name}: ${
     await anyStorage(nest, name, `chicks in ${year}`)
   }\n`; }));
   return list;
 }
```

It says the problem with this code, as I understand, is each asynchronous call e.g. `anyStorage` will actually concatenate an empty `list` and can't see the mutation from other asynchronous calls.

I tried to replicate this problem as below:

```
function delay(n) {
    return Promise.resolve(setTimeout(()=>{}, n*1000));
}

async function asyncSum(a) {
    let sum = 0;
    await Promise.all(a.map(async i => sum += await delay(i)));
    return sum;
}

asyncSum([1,2,3,4]).then(value => console.log(value));
```

But this works as expected. It prints the sum correctly.
So did I misunderstand the book or there is something wrong with my example?

Comment: a) Your `delay` function is implementing the [promisification of `setTimeout` incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/1048572) b) your `delay` function does not return a promise that resolves to the `n` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the original code is that here:

```
list += `${name}: ${ await ...
```

The `list +=` is like doing `list = list +` - but the second list:

```
list = list +
       ^^^^
```

refers to the `list` *at that moment* - before any of the asynchronous calls have completed. Eventually one of them will complete and assigns to `list`. But once the next one resolves, because the `list` it has refers to the original one, not the newly updated one, the prior results will be lost.

Here's a demo:

```js
const getMultipliedNum = num => Promise.resolve(num * 3);

(async() => {
  let list = "";
  await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(async num => {
    list += `${num}: ${ await getMultipliedNum(num)}\n`;
  }));
  console.log(list);
})();
```

Your example has the same issue, though the `delay` function is broken - the result is 4, which is only the result of the final `setTimeout` call (because `setTimeout` returns the timeout ID). Fixing it to demonstrate the problem:

```js
function delay(n) {
    return Promise.resolve(n);
}

async function asyncSum(a) {
    let sum = 0;
    await Promise.all(a.map(async i => sum += await delay(i)));
    return sum;
}

asyncSum([1,2,3,4]).then(value => console.log(value));
```

The result is 4, rather than 10 - this demonstrates that `sum += await somethingElse` inside a parallel loop doesn't work.

Another way of looking at it:

```
sum += await somethingElse
```

is like doing

```
const currentValueOfSum = sum;
sum = currentValueOfSum + await somethingElse;
```

Comment: Oh gosh, not sure why I used `setTimeOut` to simulate a promise. Silly me! Thanks for this!