# How can I get a timeOut to work inside the GraphQL root object?

Tags: javascript, graphql

In my GraphQL backend, the "employees" array is fetched and returned correctly even though it has to await its data, but the "slowEmployees" which contains a timeOut returns an empty array. How can I get "slowEmployees" to wait to return its data?

```
const root = {
    hello: () => {
        return 'hello world';
    },
    message: () => {
        return 'the message';
    },
    books: () => {
        return ['More About Linux', 'Bash Shell Scripting'];
    },
    employees: async () => {
        const rawEmployees = (
            await axios.get(
                'https://edwardtanguay.netlify.app/share/employees.json'
            )
        ).data;
        const employees = [];
        rawEmployees.forEach((rawEmployee) => {
            const employee = {
                firstName: rawEmployee.firstName,
                lastName: rawEmployee.lastName,
            };
            employees.push(employee);
        });
        return employees;
    },
    slowEmployees: () => {
        const employees = [];
        setTimeout(async () => {
            const rawEmployees = (
                await axios.get(
                    'https://edwardtanguay.netlify.app/share/employees.json'
                )
            ).data;
            rawEmployees.forEach((rawEmployee) => {
                const employee = {
                    firstName: rawEmployee.firstName,
                    lastName: rawEmployee.lastName,
                };
                employees.push(employee);
            });
        }, 2000);
        return employees;
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `setTimeout` compatible with `async/await` - [a very common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout).

If you create a "Promisified" `setTimeout`:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

... you can `await` it similarly to your regular `employees` endpoint:

```
...
slowEmployees: async () => {
    // Fetch raw data
    const rawEmployees = (
        await axios.get(
            'https://edwardtanguay.netlify.app/share/employees.json'
        )
    ).data;

    // Simulate being slow
    await timeout(2000);

    // Transform to required data shape and return
    return rawEmployees.map((rawEmployee) => {
        return {
            firstName: rawEmployee.firstName,
            lastName: rawEmployee.lastName,
        };
    });
},
```

Note I also changed your `.forEach()` + `.push` combination to a `.map()` - you're performing the transformation on each array element, with no side-effects, so it's a better semantic fit.