# Avoid backpressure in writing to NodeCSV stringify stream with async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, pipe, node-csv

How do I ensure that an output stream doesn't overflow when writing to a stream in an async/await?

Here I'm writing an array of objects as a CSV file using NodeCSV (https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv)

if I just call `await csv.write(row)` I get `Error: ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out`.
But if I add call to setTimeout with zero delay that seems to solve it, so I'm guessing the issue is backpressure exceeding capacity.  I would have expected that awaiting the write would wait until it was ready.

```
Error: ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out, write
    at writeSync (node:fs:933:3)
```

```
async function(outstream) { 
     const csv = CSV.stringify({header: true})
     csv.pipe(outstream)
     for (let row of rows) {
        await csv.write(row);
        // await timeout(0)  
     }
}
```

setTimout see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74690517/645715

Comment: Hm I notice you never call `csv.end()`, could that be the reason?

Comment: But no, [`csv.write(row)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writablewritechunk-encoding-callback) does not return a promise, the `await` is pointless. You have one long synchronous loop over all the `rows`.

Comment: You may want to consider simply [passing the data as an argument](https://csv.js.org/stringify/api/stream_callback/), simplifying the whole function to `function(outstream) { CSV.stringify(rows, {header:true}).pipe(outstream); }`. [Under the hood](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/blob/f56106dba13c2d2d91997c69341f66794e92929e/packages/csv-stringify/lib/index.js#L103-L114), that doesn't do anything different though.