Implicit Promises from async functions don't resolve as I expect
I know that all functions marked with async return a Promise object, even if it's not returned explicitly. So I made the following experiment:
async function getPromise() {
    setTimeout(() => { return "value"; }, 2000);
}

async function implicitPromiseTest() {
    const val = await getPromise();
    console.log(val);             // prints "undefined"
}

implicitPromiseTest();    

In example 1, the value after return should be implicitly wrapped in a Promise. This Promise would then be returned from the function. I expected it to be resolved in the implicitPromiseTest function and the returned value - printed to console.
I guess this doesn't work because the implicit Promise from getPromise never actually resolves. As I understand it, the proper way to do this task seems to be:
async function getPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      { setTimeout(() => { resolve("value"); }, 2000);})
}

async function implicitPromiseTest() {
    const val = await getPromise();
    console.log(val);             // prints "value"
}

But this raises questions for me:

How can I resolve a Promise returned implicitly from an async function, without explicitly returning a Promise from that function's block? Such a feature would allow me to simplify my code substantially.

If this can't be done, then what even is the point of async always implicitly returning Promises? What's the use of those Promises if they can't be resolved or rejected?

In my 2nd function, the await keyword should halt function execution until the Promise from getPromise() is resolved. And since it never resolves, the execution should stop there indefinitely. Then why does the console.log execute?



The implicit promise resolves to whatever the function returns. Since you have no return statement in getPromise(), it resolves to undefined.

The return statement in the setTimeout() callback doesn't return from getPromise().

The second version of getPromise() doesn't need to be declared async, since it returns the promise explicitly.


In example 1, the value after "return" should be implicitly wrapped in a Promise.

It's only going to wrap a promise around things you return from the async function. A value returned in a setTimeout callback function is going to be ignored.
So what's happening is: your async function starts running, then sets up a timeout, then implicitly returns undefined. Since this is an async function, that undefined gets wrapped in a promise. That promise is in a resolved state, since the function is done executing. Some time later the timeout goes off, but that has no effect on the async function which has already finished resolving its promise.
async/await exists to simplify the code for working with already-existing promises. It does not take non-promise code and convert it to promise code, except for the case where you return a non-promise. If you want to create a promise from setTimeout or any other callback-based function, then you must use the new Promise constructor.

what even is the point of async always implicitly returning Promises?

So you don't have to end all your async functions with return Promise.resolve(someValue). You can instead do return someValue
eg:
async function fetchStuff() {
  const response = await fetch('someurl');
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.userList; // instead of return Promise.resolve(data.userList)
}


In my 2nd function, the "await" keyword should halt function execution until the Promise from "getPromise()" is resolved. And since it never resolves [...]

That's a false premise. In your first example the promise resolves right away, in your second example it resolves when the timeout goes off. Now that it's resolved, any code that was awaiting it can continue

It's important to remember that async/ await is just a different way of writing Promise-based (i.e. "asynchronous") code, and it's implemented as normal Promises under the hood.
These keywords can turn Promise chains or nested promises into neater, easier to read sequential statements that look more like the rest of your synchronous code; e.g. taking this:
doWork()
.then(doMoreWork)
.then(handleCompletedWork)
.then(() => console.log('Done!'));

and writing it as more synchronous-looking, top-to-bottom executing code:
const result = await doWork();
const completedWork = await doMoreWork(result);
await handleCompletedWork(completedWork);
console.log('Done!');

Whether it's cleaner, easier to read, or more confusing, is completely up to your code and usage.
Let's break down the parts of your first example, since there are some things here that seem to be causing confusion.
Return value of async function
As you note, async functions always return promises.
This is true even when the function has no return– in this case, a Promise which resolves to the value undefined will be returned.
It's important to note, though, that the "wait" will still occur in this case; it'll just happen imperceptibly fast (as it does in your example)– you're still awaiting a Promise after all.
setTimeout
Your example seems to treat setTimeout as asynchronous, but it's not async in the Promise sense– code that calls setTimeout doesn't wait for it to fire before continuing on.
This means that getPromise() calls setTimeout and then immediately returns undefined thereafter. Making the function async just changes how that undefined is wrapped in the return to its caller, and doesn't at all change how setTimeout is treated.
This is more obvious if we log from setTimeout's callback; it fires well after getPromise is already done.


async function getPromise() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout callback fired!'), 2000);
}

async function implicitPromiseTest() {
  console.log('Calling getPromise');
  await getPromise();
  console.log('getPromise finished');
}

implicitPromiseTest();    



await
All await does in essence is unwrap/ resolve expressions.
If you await a Promise, you get the fulfillment value of that Promise (once it finishes).
If you await a non-Promise, you get the value directly (e.g. await 3 just gives you 3). There's some nuance to what counts as a Promise in this context, but this is the gist.
In your code, by calling await getPromise(), you're saying "await the result of the expression getPromise()". Upon invoking this line, your async function immediately returns a Promise, which will then resolve to the value returned by your function– which happens to be undefined here. Once your function completes, it returns that value, and the Promise resolves, and then await returns the resulting value: undefined.
You can easily get the bare Promise object by calling getPromise() without await; allowing you to pass it around, invoke await separately, or chain it with .then().


async function getPromise() { /* No return */ }

async function implicitPromiseTest() {
    const promise = getPromise();
    console.log("I'm resolved with the value:", await promise);
    promise.then(result => 
        console.log("I'm still resolved with the value:", result));
}

implicitPromiseTest();




Direct answers

How can I resolve a Promise returned implicitly from an async function, without explicitly returning a Promise from that function's block?

You're already doing this with await getPromise()! It just doesn't feel like it because of the confusions explained above.

If this can't be done, then what even is the point of async always implicitly returning Promises? What's the use of those Promises if they can't be resolved or rejected?

They can and they are; you're just awaiting it immediately, which means you never see the Promise itself.
Your code is effectively doing await Promise.resolve(undefined), which simply yields undefined.

In my 2nd function, the "await" keyword should halt function execution until the Promise from "getPromise()" is resolved. And since it never resolves, the execution should stop there indefinitely. Then why does the "console.log" execute?

Because the Promise does resolve, fulfilled with the return value of getPromise, which is undefined.
You then asked in the comments:

okay, so to re-iterate:
suppose that in:
async function getPromise() {
    setTimeout(() => { return "value"; }, 2000);
}

instead of setTimeout there was some time-consuming operation that actually took 2 seconds and then returned. Then this line in [the] 2nd function: const val = await getPromise(); would actually await the 1st function to resolve with [its] return value?

More or less, yes. I've fact-checked and reworded the section on async functions above to better address this, but you're half-right here.
If getPromise actually takes a some length amount of time to return, then you will indeed see your outer function hold at await getPromise() for that long. But that's not because it's not already "actually awaiting"– it's just that it resolves to undefined so fast that you can't see it in your example.
Here's what this would look like if getPromise actually had something to wait for:


// Promisified setTimeout via https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942
var doWork = 
  (delayMs) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r("my value"), delayMs));

async function getPromise() {
  return doWork(2000);
}

async function implicitPromiseTest() {
  console.log('Calling getPromise');
  const result = await getPromise();
  console.log(`Done awaiting, got result: "${result}"`);
}

implicitPromiseTest();




okay, so to re-iterate: suppose that in:
async function getPromise() {     setTimeout(() => { return "value"; }, 2000); }
instead of setTimeout there was some time-consuming operation that actually took 2 seconds and then returned. then this line in 2nd function:
const val = await getPromise();
would actually await the 1st function to resolve with it's return value?

@KundaliniSin Added some more to hopefully address your question!
