# how to make number generator similar to google number generator

Tags: javascript, numbers, generator

Im trying create some type of number generator on webpage. I want to show like five numbers before the generated number show. For better imagine, you can look to [google generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=number%20generator&rlz=1C1GCEU_skSK899SK899&oq=number%20generator&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.5738j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  When you click generate, it shows like 3-4 numbers before generated number. I use setInterval or setTimeout but i dont know how it works. My js code:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click",function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        setInterval(textC,5);
    }
});

function textC(){
    number.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
}
```

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `setInterval()` is that it will continue forever unless cleared, causing you to keep generating random numbers. Instead you can use `setTimeout()`, but set the timeout to change based on the value of `i` in the for loop. That way, each interval will occur 50 m/s after the other.

See example below:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const number = document.querySelector("#number");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(textC, 50 * i);
  }
});

function textC() {
  number.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
}
```

```html
<p id="number"></p>
<button>Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop ([why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380086/how-browser-executes-javascript-and-renders-asynchronously/26381899#26381899)). Just nest `setTimeout` and call it until a predefined threshold is reached. It gives you maximum control.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var number = document.querySelector("#number");
const nRuns = 12;
const timeout = 100;
let iterator = 0;

button.addEventListener( "click", textC);

function textC(){
    number.textContent = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1}\n`;
    iterator += 1;
    if (iterator < nRuns) {
      setTimeout(textC, timeout)
    } else{
      iterator = 0;
      // you control the loop, so it's time for some extra text after it
      number.textContent += ` ... and that concludes this series of random numbers`;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="number"></p>
<button>Generate</button>
```