# JavaScript: thread safety with asynchronous event callbacks? (do I need 'volatile' or something?)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, callback, volatile

Suppose I have the following code to preload 2 images, and do something only after **both** images have loaded:

```js
var numLoaded = 0;

function OnImageLoaded()
{
  numLoaded++;
  if (numLoaded==2) alert("Got 'em!");
}

var a = new Image();
var b = new Image();
a.onload = OnImageLoaded;
b.onload = OnImageLoaded;
a.src = 'foo.jpg';
b.src = 'bar.jpg';
```

Assigning `a.src` and `b.src` causes both images to be loaded in the background, and `OnImageLoaded()` being called then they're ready.

Obviously the code after `if (numLoaded==2)` is supposed to run only once.

Now, is there a possibility of this happening:

1. the first image is loaded, the function gets called, `numLoaded++` increases the counter to **one**,
2. the second image is loaded, the function gets called (in a diffrent thread), `numLoaded++` increases the counter to **two**,
3. the first thread checks `numLoaded==2` which is now true, so the code gets executed,
4. the second thread also checks `numLoaded==2` which is still true, so the supposed-to-run-once code gets executed **again** ← problem!

Is this a chance (albeit very small) and how do I avoid this? In other languages I'd use a Critical Section for this, or a mutex, or make numLoaded volatile and do `n=(++numLoaded)` or something, but how do I go about this in JS?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. For this you could use promises, for example `Promise.all([img1, img2]).then(onLoaded)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript [does not run concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718820/371184) under normal circumstances. There are ways of doing so using Node.js but it's rather difficult and not something you have to worry about for typical situations.