# javascript button disable and reenable after calculation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is the following. When I click the search button, it enters a for loop that prints 5000 times "hi". Before this calculation begins, I want to disable the button. After the console.log is finished, I want to reenable this button. But for some reason, this isn't working. (To be more precise, although here I am simply printing logs, my actually work involves various calculations that take around 5 seconds to finish using for loops.)

```
$("#search").click(function() {

   $("#search").prop("disabled",true);
   $("#search").text("Loading...");

   var i;
   for(i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
       console.log("hi");


   $("#search").prop("disabled",false);
   $("#search").text("Finished...");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gs793zhx/

Comment: This isn't working or you don't see this not working as the `for` loop is executed very fast

Comment: If you see the console, the for loop takes at least 3 seconds. However, it looks like the disabling actually happens after the for loop is executed. I believe the browser kind of freezes during the for loop.

Comment: Can ;you create demo

Comment: I have just put jfiddle

Comment: `console.log` is `async` in Safari and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.delay()` with duration set to `1` , `.queue()` , `.promise()` , `$.Deferred()`

```js
$("#search").click(function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", true)
    .text("Loading...")
    .css("color", "red")
    .delay(1, "p")
    .queue("p", function(next) {
      next()
    })
    .dequeue("p")
    .promise("p")
    .then(function() {
      var elem = this;
      return $.Deferred(function(d) {
        var i = 0, max = 50000;
        for (;i < max; i++) {
          console.log("hi");
        }
        if (i === max) {
          d.resolveWith(elem, [i])
        }
      }).promise()
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(this, data);
      $(this).prop("disabled", false)
      .css("color", "blue")
      .text("Finished...");
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px; height:30px;">SEARCH</button>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gs793zhx/1/

Comment: @user2832367 Call to `jQuery()` : `$()` could be removed from `$(this)` at last `.then()` ; same results should be returned i.e.g.; `this.prop("disabled", false)`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. By any chance, do you know why the original didn't work?

Comment: @user2832367 Appear `for` loop begins before `$("#search").prop("disabled",true);
   $("#search").text("Loading...");` complete process . See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718774/how-is-javascript-single-threaded , http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/looping-in-javascript/ . Note , if place `alert()` before `for` loop , returns expected results as well - allowing `.prop()` enough time to complete its operation https://jsfiddle.net/gs793zhx/2/

Answer (score 1):

use `$("#search").attr("disabled","disabled");` and `$("#search").removeAttr("disabled");` instead

Comment: Is it just me or this isn't working? I can't get this to work.

Comment: @user2832367, your loop seems too fast.can you try setting a little delay on your for loop using setTimeout? Replace you `console.log("hi")` line inside your loop to `setTimeout(function(){console.log("hi");},500);` then make your loop shorter to 10 only just for testing

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with browser's performance to log `hi` for `50000` times.

You may put logs into js variable and dump the variable once into the console.

```js
var btn = $("#search");
btn.click(function() {
  btn.prop("disabled", true);
  btn.text("Loading...");
  var log = [];
  for (var i = 0; 50000 > i; i++)
    log.push("i: " + i);
  console.log(log);
  btn.prop("disabled", false);
  btn.text("Finished...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='search'>Search</button>
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix this problem? Sadly, i must perform such calculation (way more complex than printing log, but a lot of for loops) with javascript front-end.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#search").click(function() {

$("#search").prop("disabled",true);
$("#search").text("Loading...");


var i;
for(i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    console.log("hi");
}
if(i==50000-1)
{
    $("#search").prop("disabled",false);
    $("#search").text("Finished...");       
}
});
```